# Array method Random number display

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, methods, random

So I am trying to make an array that call a method to randomize 100 numbers from -100 to 100
And display the Average Negative number. I keep staring at it and I cant find the error or a solution maybe I am tired but if anybody could help me I would be very thankful.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int[] P = new int[100];
        Random rand = new Random();
        float enAvg = AvgNeg(P);
        textBox1.Text = (enAvg).ToString("");
    }

    static float AvgNeg(int[] array)
    {
        float sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] < 0)
            {
                sum += array[i];
                counter++;
            }
        }
        float avg = sum / counter;
        return avg;
    }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting no error but when I press the button on my windows  form it only displays NAN or whatever it supposed to mean.

Comment: You don't appear to actually be producing any random numbers. You create an array, you create a `Random`, but you never put any numbers in the array!

Comment: where are you filling the array with random numbers? I could be blind, but I missed that part :D

Comment: wait how do I fill random numbers into my array I though it did XD

Comment: Also: `NaN` is "not a number". And that's probably because you are dividing by zero. But why are you only summing numbers if they are less than zero anyway?

Comment: @MattBurland That is what his specs say to do.

Comment: NVM I found out how to do it thanks guys for all your help :)

Comment: @Servy: My bad, I missed that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in three lines:

```
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] num = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x => r.Next(-100, 101)).ToArray();
        double avg = num.Where(n => n < 0).Average();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because all your values is zero (0), so, your `counter` variable is zero (0).
You can't divide by zero. So the float value of `avg` is NaN.

Start `counter` with value 1.

```
 int counter = 1;
```

or verify if counter is zero before divide:

```
if(counter == 0)
    return 0;
else
 {   
    float avg = sum / counter;
    return avg;
 }
```

Comment: Starting the counter at one means that the result will *always* be wrong.

Comment: The counter wasnt the problem the problem was that all the numbers in my array was 0 and it didnt randomize the number but I fix it still thanks for you help.

Comment: @TheBoringGuy If you not verify, can propably all the values randomized zeros! and the bug will occour :)

Comment: Starting the counter at `1` is not a good idea. And usually I'd argue returning `0` in the case where there were no numbers to average is also wrong (it would be better to have `float?` as you return type and return null). But in this case, because they are only averaging negative numbers (so a real average must be `<0`), it's probably okay.